# Shopware 6: Can't migrate database

Tags: database-migration, shopware, shopware6

I've followed the following tutorial for creating a custom entity on my own in shopware 6:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTHTyof4gPk

I created a migration by using

```
bin/console database:create-migration
```

and added the following code:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  'applicationmanagement' (
    'id' BINARY(26) NOT NULL,
    'name' VARCHAR (255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    'created_at' DATETIME(3) NOT NULL,
    'update_at' DATETIME(3),
    PRIMARY KEY ('id')
)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
    COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicaode_ci;
SQL;

$connection->executeUpdate($sql);
```

When I try to execute the migration by using

```
bin/console database:migrate PluginName --all
```

I get the following note

```sh
Get collection for identifier: "PluginName"

 ! [NOTE] No collection found for identifier: "PluginName", continuing
```

I tried reinstall and refresh the plugin but it didn't do anything.

Can someone help me fix this problem?

Comment: You can Xdebug into `\Shopware\Core\Framework\Migration\MigrationCollectionLoader::collect` and check the variable `$this->migrationSources` for which names are available here.

Answer (score 11):

I just had the same problem. What helped me was to clear the cache

```
bin/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by uninstalling the plugin, refreshing the plugins and after that installing and activating my plugin

Comment: I guess Shopware did not detect the change, if you did not update the version number. If you did, it would have prompted your to upgrade.

Comment: thx - had the same issue.
Followed the steps from our solution approach and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a wrong command creating migration because you didn't add Plugin name so your migration was created in shopware core - look at this
`Creating migration... Creating legacy core migration ... Migration created: "/app/shopware/dev/platform/src/Core/Migration/Migration1674222844.php" Creating core-migration ... Migration created: "/app/shopware/dev/platform/src/Core/Migration/V6_4/Migration1674222844.php"`
Look at documentation how to create migration for plugin:
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/database-migrations
command- `$ ./bin/console database:create-migration -p SwagBasicExample --name ExampleDescription`